# Generate random string visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I don't understand how to add numbers to the random string, and instead of it showing a string of like 3 sometimes, I want it to always show a string of 5 and I have no clue how to do that.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rndnumber As Random
    Dim number As Integer
    rndnumber = New Random
    number = rndnumber.Next(1, 80000)
    TextBox1.Text = number.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, it still generates 4 letters and smaller numbers.

Comment: Try this: TextBox1.Text = number.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0'). You can also use PadRight depending on whichever you want

Answer (score 4):

You could use this function to create random strings:

```
Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef len As Integer, ByRef upper As Boolean) As String
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim allowableChars() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
    Dim final As String = String.Empty
    For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
        final += allowableChars(rand.Next(allowableChars.Length - 1))
    Next

    Return IIf(upper, final.ToUpper(), final)
End Function
```

You can call this function like this:

```
GenerateRandomString(5, False)
```

First parameter is number of characters and second is if you want upper case characters or not (True or False).

Comment: I tried this but nothing came out of the generate box. I added the function then I went and called the function on the on click generate and tested it but it didn't work.

Comment: I tested the code in Visual Studio (Visual Basic.Net) it works you could try like this:
Dim text As String 
text = GenerateRandomString(5, False)
Console.WriteLine(text)

If you want the numbers in random you could change this line:
 Dim allowableChars() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
    to "12313827481274971289418947128471748912741894781"
it works.

Comment: `Random.Next(maxValue As Integer)` shouldn't return an Integer **less** than `maxValue`? Then `allowableChars.Length` should be enough and correct, since `rand.Next()` will always skip the last member of `allowableChars` otherwise

Answer (score 1):

This generates a random string number of length 5:

```
final = rdm.Next(0, 100000).ToString("00000")
```

And this function generates a random string of everything of any length:

```
Public Function GetRandomString(ByVal iLength As Integer) As String
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Dim rdm As New Random()

    For i As Integer = 1 To iLength
        sResult &= ChrW(rdm.Next(32, 126))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be a string of numbers?, because if not, you could use System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName. This function gives you a random uppercase string of any length, with a default of eight characters

```
Public Function GetRandomString(Optional ByVal iLength As Integer = 8) As String
    Dim sPath, SResult As String

    sPath = ""
    Do
        sPath = sPath + System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName.Replace(".", "")
    Loop Until sPath.Length > iLength
    SResult = sPath.Substring(0, iLength)
    Return SResult.ToUpper
End Function
```